# navigate back to the page with the selected item in the current page?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have one doubt in wp7. I have three pages. Main page, first page and second page. 
I have navigated from the main page to the first page easily and design the first page dynamically, with the data from the database. The first page contains text blocks, that i loaded data from db. And the second page, contains a list of items in the list box that will generated dynamically. I navigated from first page to the second page easily, using navigation service function.

My doubt is: From the list of items in the second page, we need to select one item, and again navigate back to the first page and display the selected item in the text block in the first page. How to do it? please help me with some piece of code... Thank You..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do that is to provide a static attribute in your code.

For example, put that in your second page c#

```
public static Object SelectedItem;
```

And retrieve it from the first page in this way:

```
Object selectedItem = SecondPage.SelectedItem;
```

Of course this code is for sample, no production-ready. But here is the idea.

Comment: Thank You, Very much... It help me a lot. Thanks to StackOverFlow website.